# CUDA global memory access speed

Tags: memory, cuda, global

here is simple cuda code.
I am testing the time of accessing global memory. read and right.

below is kernel function(test1()).

```
enter code here

__global__ void test1(int *direct_map)   
{  
    int index = 10;  
    int index2;  

    for(int j=0; j<1024; j++)  
    {  
        index2 = direct_map[index];  
        direct_map[index] = -1;  
        index = index2;  
    }  
}
```

direct_map is 683*1024 linear matrix and, each pixel has a offset value to access to other pixel.
index and index2 is not continued address.

this kernel function needs about **600** micro second.

But, if i delete the code,
direct_map[index] = -1;

just takes **27** micro second.

I think the code already read the value of direct_map[index] from global memory from

index2 = direct_map[index];

then, it should be located L2 cache.
So, when doing "direct_map[index] = -1;", the speed should be fast.

And, I tested random writing to global memory(test2()).

It takes about **120** micro seconds.

```
enter code here

__global__ void test2(int *direct_map)   
{  
    int index = 10;  

    for(int j=0; j<1024; j++)  
    {  
        direct_map[index] = -1;  
        index = j*683 + j/3 - 1;  
    }  
}
```

So, I don't know why test1() takes over than 600 micro seconds.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete the code line:

```
direct_map[index] = -1;
```

your kernel isn't doing anything *useful*.  The compiler can recognize this and eliminate most of the code associated with the kernel launch.  That modification to the kernel code means that the kernel no longer affects any *global state* and the code is effectively useless, from the compiler's perspective.

You can verify this by dumping the assembly code that the compiler generates in each case, for example with `cuobjdump -sass myexecutable`

Anytime you make a small change to the code and see a large change in timing, you should suspect that the change you made has allowed the compiler to make different optimization decisions.